# ios UITableViewController add admob banner

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I need to add a static adMob view banner (not native) to UITableViewController. I use

```
[self.view addSubview:bannerView];
```

which works fine, but it overlap with the tableview. Is it possible to insert it on top of tableview ?

Thank you for advices,
Rado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the view as a header to the tableView

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = bannerView;
```

or You can bring the view to front with your implementation

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [bannerView.superview bringSubviewToFront:bannerView];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that solution is fine for me. But can I make the ad banner show over the table banner even I scroll down to table view?

Comment: you can either use a `UIViewContoller` instead and add the view with your implementation or in `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate method you can use `bringViewToFront` on self.bannerView.superView with the banner view as a parameter also with your implementation